# Calculating euler number of disk

Tags: string-theory, differential-geometry, geometry

I'm trying to do exercise 3.1 from Polchinski, which should be a rather easy differential geometry problem. I have to calculate the euler number defined by 
$$\chi = \frac{1}{4\pi}\int_{M}d^{2}\sigma g^{1/2}R + \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{\partial M}ds k$$ where the geodesic curvature $k$ is defined by $$k = \pm t^{a}n_{b}\nabla_{a}t^{b}$$
I have to calculate $\chi$ for the flat disk and the disk with the metric of a hemisphere. It is easy for me to do this using cellular homology, which easily gives the euler characteristic of $\chi = 1$, (since the closed disk is contractible, and the higher homology groups vanish).

However, I do not have that much experience doing calculations in differential geometry. I understand that the Ricci scalar vanishes for the case of the flat disk, but how would one calculate the scalar curvature in this case? In particular, how should the calculation be carried out for the disk with the metric of the hemisphere? If it's possible, please include the details in the calculation.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's do this explicitly for both cases. For these examples, the classical formula for the geodesic curvature $k_g$ suffices. Let $\gamma(t)$ be a curve in a surface $S \subset \mathbb{R}^3$, and let $n(t)$ be the unit normal to $S$ at the point $\gamma(t)$. Then $$ k_g = \frac{\ddot{\gamma}(t) .(n(t) \times \dot{\gamma}(t))}{|\dot{\gamma}(t)|^3} $$

First the case where we take the disk with the flat metric and unit radius. Then $R = 0$ and we only have to worry about the geodesic curvature $k_g$. Here our surface is $\mathbb{R}^2$ and we parametrize the boundary of our disk as $\gamma(t) = (\text{cos}(t), \text{sin}(t),0)$, and $n = (0,0,1)$ throughout. Then a simple calculation shows that $k_g = 1$. Therefore $$\chi(\text{flat disk}) = \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{0}^{2\pi} dt \,\,1 = 1$$

Now lets take the representation of the disk as a hemisphere with the round metric. In fact let's be more general: Let $S^2$ be the sphere of radius 1. The $z=a$ plane where $a \in (-1,1)$ splits $S^2$ into two parts. We can take our disk to be the upper part and call it $D_a$ (note that $D_0$ is the hemisphere). To compute $\chi(D_a)$ we note that in general both terms will be present, since $\partial D_a$ is only a geodesic (and thus $k_g = 0$) for $a=0$. Therefore both terms play a role and we compute them separately. The first term is easy: $R = 2$ still, (since as was mentioned by Jerry, the pullback operator to $D_a$ is trivial) so the first term reads $$\frac{1}{4\pi} \int_{D_a} d\theta \,d\phi\, \text{sin}(\theta) \,\, 2 = 1-a .$$

For $k_g$, note that since $\partial D_a$ is a circle of radius $(1-a^2)^{1/2}$ centered at $(0,0,a)$ (drawing a picture is helpful) it can be parametrized by $$\gamma(t) = ((1-a^2)^{1/2} \,\text{cos}(t), (1-a^2)^{1/2} \,\text{sin}(t), \,a)$$ and $$n(t) = ((1-a^2)^{1/2} \text{cos}(t), (1-a^2)^{1/2} \text{sin}(t), a).$$ You can then compute $$k_g = \frac{a}{(1-a^2)^{1/2}}.$$ The second term is then $$\frac{1}{2\pi}  (\int_{\partial D_a})\frac{a}{(1-a^2)^{1/2}} = a .$$

Therefore $$\chi(D_a) = (1-a) + a = 1 = \chi(\text{flat disk})$$ as we expected.

Comment: Thanks, that makes it clear. I thought there would be a shortcut, but one still needs to chug through the computation. So where does the relation $t^{a}\nabla_{a}t^{b} = -n^{b}$ come from? Is it because the christoffel symbols vanish for the flat case?

Comment: As for the equivalence of the two formulas describing the geodesic curvature, I'd have to think about it since I've only explicitly worked with the classical one I wrote above. It is written out in terms of Christoffel symbols here:

http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GeodesicCurvature.html

Comment: Thanks. It'd be nice to see how the two formulas related and how the above relation is true in this case.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use the metric of the hemisphere.  This is because the pullback of arbitrary forms onto the submanifold is the trivial pullback operator.  All you need to do is apply the projection operator.  Therefore, the extrinsic curvature tensor is just $K_{ab} = - \gamma_{a}{}^{c}\gamma_{b}{}^{d}\nabla_{c}n_{d}$, where $\gamma_{ab}$ is the metric of the submanifold (or if you prefer, $\gamma_{a}{}^{b}$ is the projection operator onto the submanifold from the enveloping space), and $\nabla$ is the connection of the enveloping space.

It depends on what you mean by $t^{a}$ and $n^{a}$, but it should be easy enough to prove that this experession is equivalent to yours, if you take the correct contraction and leverage a few identities.

Comment: So for the flat disk, would the curvature tensor just be $K_{ab} = -\delta_{a}^{c}\delta_{b}^{d}\nabla_{c}n_{d} = -\nabla_{a}n_{b}$? Does this just evaluate to 1?

Comment: In general given the metric, how would one compute the geodesic curvature? I understand the covariant derivative just decomposes into the sum of a partial derivative and christoffel symbols, which are straightforwardly computed using the given metric, but how should the $t^{a}, n_{b}$, the tangent and normal unit vectors be manipulated?

Comment: @user238194, not if $n_{a}$ is the unit outward normal.  In 2d, this is $n_{a} = (x/r)dx + (y/r)dx$, which does not have zero derivative.

Comment: Is your manifold a disk in 2-dimensional flat space?  For a d dimensional submanifold of a D dimensional space, you generically have $D-d$ normal vectors and $d$ tangent vectors.

Comment: Yes, we are working in 2-dimensional flat space

Comment: I read that $t^{a}\nabla_{a}t^{b}$ evaluates to $n^{b}$. How is this calculation carried out? And for the disk with the metric of a hemisphere, it is stated that the boundary is just a geodesic. Is it obvious to see this conclusion?

Comment: @user238194: for your first question, I'd project your first expression into tangent and normal components.  For your second question, what is the boundary of a hemisphere?  What do you know about geodesics on spheres?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not adept with tensor manipulation. What projection tensor would one use to project into tangent/normal components?

The only thing I remember is that the curves that satisfy the geodesic equations on $S^{2}$ are the great circles.

Comment: Would it be possible for you to sketch a calculation for the geodesic curvature? I just want to see a calculation for this case, so that I would know how to calculate it in general.

Comment: $t^{a}\nabla_{a}t^{b}$ is a vector.  you could write this as $\left({\vec v}\cdot {\vec \nabla}\right){\vec v}$.  How on Earth are you working through Polchinski if this is over your head?

Comment: Sorry, I haven't done differential geometry in a while. The first two chapters didn't really have much riemannian geometry in it either, save for a few problems on varying the metric and trivial tensor manipulations.

Answer (score 1):

Disk: The Ricci scalar is trivially zero because the disk flat. $t^b\nabla_b t^a$ measures the "acceleration" of the boundary's tangent vector. You can convince yourself this is proportional to the normal vector, $t^b\nabla_b t^a=- n^a$. No differential geometry required here, just calculate the acceleration vector of a particle traveling along a unit circle at unit speed. Contracting both sides with $n$ gives $k=1$, i.e.
$$\chi=\underbrace{\frac{1}{4\pi}\int_D\sqrt{g}R\,\mathrm{d}^2x}_{0}+\underbrace{\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}\mathrm{d}\theta}_1=1$$

Hemisphere: The Ricci curvature of a general 2-sphere is $2/r^2$. For the unit 2-sphere this is $R=2$. The measure is $\sqrt{g}\mathrm{d}^2x=\sin\theta\,\mathrm{d}\theta\mathrm{d}\phi$. We inegrate this over $0\le\theta<\pi/2$ and $0\le\phi<2\pi$. That integral gives $4\pi$. The boundary of a hemisphere is a great circle, a geodesic, so $t^b\nabla_b t^a=0$ by the geodesic equation, and we have $k=0$. Putting it all together, we obtain
$$\chi=\frac{1}{4\pi}\underbrace{\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^{\pi/2}2\sin\theta\,\mathrm{d}\theta\mathrm{d}\phi}_{4\pi}+\underbrace{\frac{1}{2\pi}\int k\,\mathrm{d}s}_0=1$$